# Cloud SQL Admin API for Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

How can I use Cloud SQL admin API to change the IP allowed to connect to a public sql instance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [API Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/patch)

It looks like you should be able to PATCH against an instance passing authorized networks

```
{
  "settings": {
    "ipConfiguration": {
      "authorizedNetworks": []
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found this in update, have a look:

> settings.ipConfiguration.authorizedNetworks[] list    The list of
>   external networks that are allowed to connect to the instance using
>   the IP. In CIDR notation, also known as 'slash' notation (e.g.
>   192.168.100.0/24).

There are many more options of what you can do [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/update).